# How are encoded semicolons ending up in my querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, query-string

I am setting the src of an iframe in my codebehind like this:

```
iframe.Attributes.Add("src", string.Format("/page.aspx?a={0}&b={1}", aVal, bVal);
```

I realized that on rare occasion the following is true on page.aspx:

```
Request.QueryString["b"] == null
```

I started logging some of the request data and out of the few thousand time this page gets accessed each day the data will typically look like this:

```
Request.Url: http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?a=1&b=2
Request.Referrer: http://www.mydomain.com/referrer/
Request.Querystring: a=1&b=2
```

About a half dozen times per day, the data will look like this:

```
Request.Url: http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?a=1&b=2
Request.Referrer: http://www.mydomain.com/referrer/
Request.QueryString: a=1&%3bb=2
```

You will notice everything is exactly the same except a URL encoded semicolon, %3b, appears in the query string. The referrer URL tells me that page.aspx is being accessed correctly and not being manually entered into the browser by a user. This page is also in a secure members only area and I confirmed that this is happening to random users for random content. I cannot reproduce this - if I go to the Request.Url value, %3b never appears in the query string, and if I go to the Request.Referrer value to access the content the same way a customer would, %3b never appears in the query string. The Request.Referrer value is the only page that loads page.aspx.

Any ideas how the %3b could possibly be getting into the query string?

Comment: Do you by any chance log the user agent so as to correlate it when this happens?

Comment: Could it be that the query string arg separator is being encoded as `&amp;`? Just a thought.

Comment: "About a half dozen times per day" usually means "a badly written robot scanned my page, made a mess of it, and queried the wrong url" - which probably ties into Kirk's user-agent query.

Comment: @Kirk, I did not think to do that. I'll add it in and see what I get. Thanks.

Comment: The user agent didn't turn up any information I could use to figure out what was going on. I guess another thing I'm not understanding is how %3b is in the query string but a semicolon isn't in the Request.Url... I can't even figure out how to reproduce that. I would expect the Request.Url to look like this, as it is how it looks when I try to reproduce: http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?a=1&;b=2.

Comment: @Brian, I tried to remove the %3b (Request.QueryString.ToString().Replace("%3b", string.Empty)) and then include the resulting string in my log. What resulted from this was a=1&ampb=2, and the original Request.QueryString value was still a=1&%3bb=2. Any idea why this is happening?